# Apache mod rewrite, rewrite for all .php requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url to port 8001 if the requested filename is a .php file to be mysite.com:8001/requestedfile.php Apache 2.2.15 on RHEL 5.  I want this to be internal, port 8001 is not opened on the OS firewall (iptables).  IF this should be done differently, please let me know.

Here is what I tried:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*\.php$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8001/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this? The 8000 level ports are usually used by Java apps by convention.

Comment: 80 is already being redirected to 8009 for Tomcat for all requests, but the developers want /blog to go to Drupal now which is at a completely different DocumentRoot in the filesystem, so I created a ProxyPassReverse to redirect /blog to 8001 and put a VirtualHost on *:8001, but when /blog/install.php is run to install Drupal, it rewrites the URL to /install.php which then gets redirected to Tomcat.  Not sure whiy this happens ,but this is to keep it on port 8001 for Drupal internally.  Perhaps it is Drupal's .htaccess doing this?

Comment: Ditch drupal? I kid I kid. Honestly I'm confused as well.

Comment: I think the ajp proxy was cast with too wide a net, but I was able to get out in front by doing the URL rewriting in the proxy ajp config.  Drupal would not be my first choice, I am more familiar with Wordpress personally, but I'm just the sysadmin, I only need to get it online, the CMS choice isn't really my say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can enable `mod_proxy` then you can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8001$
RewriteRule \.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P,NC]
```

Comment: Don't you mean Mod_Rewrite?

Comment: OK I see now, can you please add a check/RewriteCond to only append port if it isn't already there?  I have another proxypass which does append in some cases and this breaks it.

Comment: That is what I tried, something is not working, I think because the DocumentRoot is changing to the Tomcat DocRoot when the request changes from /blog/install.php to /install.php (at this point I get a 404 from Tomcat).  I tried creating an .htaccess in the Tomcat Docroot with the same condition and rule but it seems to not be working though I set Allowoverride all.

Comment: I think I found it, his proxy ajp config was too inclusive so it was sending the request to Tomcat on 8009 before other processing took place. I put these directives in the proxy ajp config file and it seems to work, it was an ordering issue I guess.